# Dockerfile: Install nginx and node for an Angular App

Tags: angular, dockerfile, github-actions

I have a basic Angular app and have the following Dockerfile input which works fine if I build locally

```
# Stage 1
FROM nginx:stable-alpine AS build
FROM node:18.10.0 AS build
WORKDIR /usr/test/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2

# Use official nginx tested image as the base image
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/test/app/dist/app-dest /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Actions File

```
name: Docker Test

on:
 workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          persist-credentials: false

      - name: Use HTTPS authentication
        uses: GuillaumeFalourd/SSH-to-HTTPS@v1

      - name: Install Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.10.0

      - name: Build Image
        run: docker build . --file Dockerfile
```

However when I try to build a docker via Github Actions I get the error

```
build stage name already used
```

If I removed AS build from node line I get a different error in GitHub actions as the app-dest is not found

So what is the correct way to define in Dockerfile for build of an angular app which requires nginx and node version to work with Github Actions?

Should I simply do ? (Get rid of nginx from Stage 1)

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:18.10.0 AS build
....

# Stage 2
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/test/app/dist/app-dest /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: You want to run both node and nginx in the same container? What does your `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` look like?

Comment: @Azeem I am new to this so might be getting it wrong.. Don't have either .. Full Dockerfile is posted above.. Its a basic Angular App with Node and deploying on nginx.. What will be the proper Dockerfile for it?

Comment: Right. How would be deploying it? Generally, you should be packaging the app with its runtime and the nginx should be deployed along side it routing traffic to it.

Comment: @Azeem electron-packager is used for normal deployment. But above we build the app with node and into nginx and that is put in the image.

Comment: Where is it deployed after packaging?

Comment: Docker Hub Registry using docker/build-push-action@v3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252809/discussion-between-chris-t-and-azeem).

Comment: You may self-answer this using the final version that you come up with to help future readers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to do

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:18.10.0 AS build
WORKDIR /usr/test/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2
FROM nginx:1.22.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/test/app/dist/app-dest /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Thanks @Azeem